# How to copy cells in a dataframe in ascending order until another number is reached? Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following column within my dataframe:

```
First Date

2006-05-05




2006-09-30
2007-05-26
2007-05-28
2007-07-21


2008-01-10
2008-05-16

2008-10-08
2008-11-09

2009-04-11
2009-04-25
```

As you can see, there are a few NaN cells sparsely throughout the column.  What I need is to take the date below the NaN cells and copy them into the cells above them.  The desired output is this:

```
First Date
2006-05-05
2006-05-05
2006-09-30
2006-09-30
2006-09-30
2006-09-30
2006-09-30
2007-05-26
2007-05-28
2007-07-21
2008-01-10
2008-01-10
2008-01-10
2008-05-16
2008-10-08
2008-10-08
2008-11-09
2009-04-11
2009-04-11
2009-04-25
```

How should I go about doing this in pandas for python?

Comment: That's backward fill, `df['First Date'].bfill()`, if the values are `NaN`, but if the values are empty string `''`, then replace them first by `NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you need "***bfill***" or "***backfill***" by ***method*** in ***fillna***. Let me show you with additional codes.

```
# backfill / bfill: use next valid observation to fill gap
data['Fill Date bfill 2'] = data['Date'].bfill()
data['Fill Date bfill 1'] = data['Date'].fillna(method='bfill')
data['Fill Date backfill'] = data['Date'].fillna(method='backfill')

# pad / ffill: propagate last valid observation forward to next valid 
data['Fill Date ffill'] = data['Date'].fillna(method='ffill')
data['Fill Date pad'] = data['Date'].fillna(method='pad')
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

You simply need `bfill()`:

```
df['First Date'] = df['First Date'].bfill()
```

Your original df:

```
>>> df
    First Date
0          NaN
1   05/05/2006
2          NaN
3          NaN
4          NaN
5          NaN
6   30/09/2006
7   26/05/2007
8   28/05/2007
9   21/07/2007
10         NaN
11         NaN
12  10/01/2008
13  16/05/2008
14         NaN
15  08/10/2008
16  09/11/2008
17         NaN
18  11/04/2009
```

Imputed after running above line:

```
    First Date
0   05/05/2006
1   05/05/2006
2   30/09/2006
3   30/09/2006
4   30/09/2006
5   30/09/2006
6   30/09/2006
7   26/05/2007
8   28/05/2007
9   21/07/2007
10  10/01/2008
11  10/01/2008
12  10/01/2008
13  16/05/2008
14  08/10/2008
15  08/10/2008
16  09/11/2008
17  11/04/2009
18  11/04/2009
```

As mentioned in the comments make sure that the values are actually `NaN`